# Django: Nested templates such as {{ foo.{{ bar.baz }} }}

Tags: django, django-templates, nested

I have a Django template that calls an object’s field, such as `object.dictionary.key`.

The thing is, the value of `key` I would want is itself given by `other_variable.other_field`.

Is `{% object.dictionary.{{ other_variable.other_field }} %}` legal? Is there a workaround?

I've been poking around for answers to Django nested-template questions, but none of them seem to be asking exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a dictionary, the following should just work:

{{ object.dictionary.other_variable.other_field }}

Comment: No, because `other_variable.other_field` should evaluate to the key of the dictionary.